# Return value of Controller should be ignored

Tags: spring-mvc

For test reasons I'd like to have a method signature in a spring-mvc-controller with a return value which should be ignored by spring:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/{uuid}", params = "question", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public IAnswer saveAnswer(UiAnswer json, @PathVariable String uuid, @RequestParam("question") String question, HttpServletResponse response) {}
```

It's a post-request where the controller receives data and just responses with `response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);` if everything went fine.

- With `@ResponseBody` it dies in a internal server error 500
- Without `@ResponseBody` spring tries to resolve the view
- With `void` as the return value, it works fine

Can I tell spring to ignore my returned object?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{uuid}", params = "question", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void saveAnswer(UiAnswer json, 
                       @PathVariable String uuid, 
                       @RequestParam("question") String question, 
                       HttpServletResponse response) {
    doSaveAnswer(json, uuid, question, response);
}

protected IAnswer doSaveAnswer(UiAnswer json, 
                               String uuid, 
                               String question, 
                               HttpServletResponse response) {
    // your original code here
}
```

Then unit-test `doSaveAnswer()`.

Comment: Mmmm looks like a typical service implementation... maybe the OP should be using a service layer, not only it is easier to test but you get all the other benefits of N-tier architecture...